# Change names of months and days of week in DatePicker for windows phone

Tags: datepicker, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

In datepicker tool for windows phone, the names of months and days of week has been written under each cell(e.g February or Wednesday)

[image]

Is there anyway to change theme or remove them??
I'd searched over the net but nothing found ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior and cannot be changed. Good thing is, you can always [download the toolkit source](http://phone.codeplex.com/) and recompile it without the day/month blocks.